# How to set the RHS when using ode45 in matlab if I have to use some parameter which depends on the solution in each time step?

Tags: matlab, ode45

```
y(1)' = y(2);

y(2)' = [-y(1)-y(2)^2]/(y(1)+C0);

y(3)' = y(3)/y(4)*y(2)*C1;

y(4)' = y(2)*FF;
```

`C0`, `C1`, `C2` and `C3` are Const., `FF` is `C2*y(3)^0.5` if `y(3) > 100`; `FF` is `C3*y(3)^0.5` if `y(3)<=100`.

How to set `y(4)'` in this situation?

I tried `y(4)' = y(2)*((y(3) > 100)*C2*y(3)^0.5 + (y(3)<=100)*C3*y(3)^0.5);` It didn't work. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

The equations above were simplified.

Well, after several tests with ode15s and other solvers, I realized that the matrix was close to singular. So the physical condition is the problem.

Comment: What you tried should work.  Can you explain why it didn't and possibly provide the complete code so we can run it?

Comment: Please see the revised question and codes. Thank you so much. @TroyHaskin